# Custom Description for Stripe Payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization, stripe-payments

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to send information along with Stripe transactions to populate the "description" field with each purchase. Basically, I want this to include information from the purchase page that the payment form is on. I have a value on each purchase page that displays the school that a user is contributing to (<%= @pin.school %>). I want to be able to pull this same value into each payment description so that I know which school the user contributed to. I feel like I have myself and my app confused on which methods to use to make this happen between my form page and my charges controller that actually processes form submissions and sends them to Stripe.

"Charges" Controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_ESb8aYrhEOcrNXr3940KehVM"
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500
    @school = @pin.school

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => @amount, 
      :currency => "usd",
      :card => params[:stripeToken],
      :description => @school
    )
  end
end
```

Payment Page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // this identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_j8hulWlnmbug4H14Q0emQixf');

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $('.submit-button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        var $form = $('#payment-form');
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        var email = $("#email").val();
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    }

    $(function() {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('.submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
        var email = $("#email").val();

        Stripe.createToken({
          name: $('.card-name').val(),
          number: $('.card-number').val(),
          cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
          exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
          exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10 offset1">
        <div class="well">
            Level 1
            <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <p>
                Level 2
                </p>
                <p>
                <%= image_tag @pin.image %>
                </p>
                <p>
                <% if current_user == @pin.user %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> |
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
                </p>
                </div>
            <div class="span4">Level 3
                <h1>
                    <%= @pin.user.name %>
                </h1>
                <p>
                    <b>School:</b>
                    <%= @pin.school %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>My Story:</b>
                    <%= @pin.description %>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <b>Starting Balance:</b>
                    <%= @pin.loan_orig %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Current Balance:</b>
                    <%= @pin.loan_cur %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Progress:</b>
                </p>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
                  <div class="bar" style="width: 40%"></div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <b>Share this profile:</b>
                    <%= request.url %>
                </p>


        <!--Start Stripe Form -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">       
            <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <span class="payment-errors"></span>
                        <form action="/charges" method="POST" id="payment-form"class="form-stacked">

                            <p class="form-label">Email Address:</p>
                                     <input class="text" id="email" spellcheck="false"></input>


                        <div class="form-row" "pull-left">
                            <label>
                              <span>Name</span>
                              <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-name"/>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-row" "pull-left">
                            <label>
                              <span>Card Number</span>
                              <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number"/>
                            </label>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-row" "pull-left">
                            <label>
                              <span>Security Code (CVC)</span>
                              <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc"/>
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        <div class="form-row" "pull-right">
                            <label>Expiry Date</label>
                              <select class="card-expiry-month">
                                <option selected="selected" value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-row" "pull-right">
                            <select class="card-expiry-year">
                                <option selected="selected" value="2013">2013</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                                <option value="2029">2029</option>
                                <option value="2030">2030</option>
                                <option value="2031">2031</option>
                                <option value="2032">2032</option>
                                <option value="2033">2033</option>
                                <option value="2034">2034</option>
                                <option value="2035">2035</option>
                                <option value="2036">2036</option>
                                <option value="2037">2037</option>
                                <option value="2038">2038</option>
                                </select>
                          </div> 
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Payment</button>
                        </form>
                <!--End Stripe Form -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to update to version 2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```